# how to use foreign key in Room persistence library

Tags: android, android-room

I am working with room persistence library in android, i would appreciate if someone can help me in using foreign key, how to get data by using foreign key.

Comment: There is an excellent [Blog post](https://android.jlelse.eu/android-architecture-components-room-relationships-bf473510c14a) regarding Usage of Room  Relationships with foreignKeys

Comment: one more thing, Is it mandatory to create multiple DAOs when we’re creating multiple entities.If no then please tell how to implement multiple DAOs in a single one.

Comment: It is better when you create multiple DAO's as it separates each other. It's one of the important rule in [SOLID Principles](https://academy.realm.io/posts/donn-felker-solid-part-1)

Comment: yeah it'll be convenient to use multiple DAOs instead of single. but we can use single DAO as well . . . Right???

Comment: I haven't tried it, so cant comment on it Sorry

Comment: @NirmalPrajapat it is not a good pratice to use one DAO ! Use one DAO for one entity. This way it is easier to read the code too.

Comment: https://medium.com/@magdamiu/android-room-persistence-library-relations-75bbe02e8522 check this

Comment: I am, for testing some room things, currently using one DAO with multiple async tasks inside that handle different inserts. Works well. @NirmalPrajapat

Answer (score 148, accepted):

Just to summarize the above posts for future readers:

The foreign key syntax in Kotlin is

```
@Entity(foreignKeys = arrayOf(ForeignKey(entity = ParentClass::class,
                    parentColumns = arrayOf("parentClassColumn"),
                    childColumns = arrayOf("childClassColumn"),
                    onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE)))
```

The foreign key syntax in Java is:

```
@Entity(foreignKeys = {@ForeignKey(entity = ParentClass.class,
    parentColumns = "parentClassColumn",
    childColumns = "childClassColumn",
    onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE)
})
```

Note: foreignKeys is an array, so in Java enclose @ForeignKey elements in { and }

You can refer to the official documentation for more information.
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/ForeignKey

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to actually present a show and tell. While others are busy just throwing links to content that may eventually change in the future.

Comment: Is it compulsory to use `foreignKeys` inside `Entity` or can we use `@Relation` annotation only?

Answer (score 65):

Here how you can define and access a One-to-many ([Foreign Key](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp)) relationship in Android Jetpack Room. Here the Entities are `Artist` and `Album` and the foreign key is `Album.artist`

```kt
@Entity
data class Artist(
    @PrimaryKey
    val id: String,
    val name: String
)

@Entity(
    foreignKeys = [ForeignKey(
        entity = Artist::class,
        parentColumns = arrayOf("id"),
        childColumns = arrayOf("artist"),
        onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
    )]
)
data class Album(
    @PrimaryKey
    val albumId: String,
    val name: String,
    @ColumnInfo(index = true)
    val artist: String
)
```

then the embedded object ([read official Android documentation: Define relationships between objects](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships))

```
data class ArtistAndAlbums(
    @Embedded
    val artist: Artist,
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "id",
        entityColumn = "artist"
    )
    val albums: List<Album>
)
```

And finally the `DAO`

```
@Dao
interface Library {
    @Insert
    suspend fun save(artist: Artist)

    @Insert
    suspend fun save(vararg album: Album)

    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM artist")
    suspend fun getAll(): List<ArtistAndAlbums>

    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM artist WHERE id = :id")
    suspend fun getByArtistId(id: String): ArtistAndAlbums
}
```

**trying this out, (all these operations happens inside a Coroutine)**

```
// creating objects
val artist = Artist(id="hillsongunited", name="Hillsong United" )
val artist2 = Artist(id="planetshakers", name="Planet Shakers" )

val album1 = Album(albumId = "empires", name = "Empires", artist = artist.id)
val album2 = Album(albumId = "wonder", name = "Wonder", artist = artist.id)
val album3 = Album(albumId = "people", name = "People", artist = artist.id)

val album4 = Album(albumId = "rain", name = "Rain", artist = artist2.id)
val album5 = Album(albumId = "itschristmas", name = "Its Christmas", artist = artist2.id)
val album6 = Album(albumId = "overitall", name = "Over It All", artist = artist2.id)

// saving to database
SongDatabase.invoke(applicationContext).library().save(artist)
SongDatabase.invoke(applicationContext).library().save(artist2)
SongDatabase.invoke(applicationContext).library().save(album1, album2, album3, album4, album5, album6)
```

**Logging all Artists**

```
val all = SongDatabase.invoke(applicationContext).library().getAll()
Log.d("debug", "All Artists $all ")

D/debug: All Artists [ArtistAndAlbums(artist=Artist(id=hillsongunited, name=Hillsong United), albums=[Album(albumId=empires, name=Empires, artist=hillsongunited), Album(albumId=wonder, name=Wonder, artist=hillsongunited), Album(albumId=people, name=People, artist=hillsongunited)]), ArtistAndAlbums(artist=Artist(id=planetshakers, name=Planet Shakers), albums=[Album(albumId=rain, name=Rain, artist=planetshakers), Album(albumId=itschristmas, name=Its Christmas, artist=planetshakers), Album(albumId=overitall, name=Over It All, artist=planetshakers)])]
```

**Logging albums by a specific artist,**

```
val hillsongAlbums = SongDatabase.invoke(applicationContext).library().getByArtistId(artist.id)
Log.d("debug", "Albums by artist ID: $hillsongAlbums ")

D/debug: Albums by artist ID: ArtistAndAlbums(artist=Artist(id=hillsongunited, name=Hillsong United), albums=[Album(albumId=empires, name=Empires, artist=hillsongunited), Album(albumId=wonder, name=Wonder, artist=hillsongunited), Album(albumId=people, name=People, artist=hillsongunited)])
```

Comment: For `one-to-many` relationships you should rename `ArtistAndAlbums` with `ArtistWithAlbums`.

Comment: @SumitShukla its just a naming convention, nothing to do with the naming actually.

Comment: Usually ```id``` of an entity is autogenerated and is not available until the entity has been inserted. You have to insert a ```parent entity``` first, receive its ```id``` and supply it to a ```child entity```. Everything should go in transaction for this use case.

Answer (score 11):

`@ForeignKey` annotations are not used to define relations when ***getting*** data but to define relations when ***modifying*** data. To get relational data from a Room databse, Google recommends the `@Relation` along with the `@Embedded` annotation.

You can check out [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67006942/9907909) for more explanation if you're interested.